# Hhow to get back to "Get Recommendations" blade again?

Tags: azure

How to disable Azure Advisor Recommendations and get back to "Get Recommendations" blade again after activating the get Recommendations blade once.

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** To **snooze** or **dismiss** a recommendation, click the Snooze button or link. You can specify a snooze time period or select Never to dismiss the recommendation.

**To disable the recommendations blade:**

Step1: Open **Advisor** => Select any **Recommendation**

[image]

Step 2:  Open the **recommendation**

[image]

Step 3:  Click on **Snooze** => select **Never** => click on **Snooze**.

[image]

**To get back the recommendation blade:**

Step 1: You may select both the **Active** and **Snoozed** by select here

[image]

Step 2: Open the Recommendation

[image]

Step 3: Click on Active

[image]

Comment: If I select one recommendation and click on snooze->Never, will it stop permanently? I need to see Get Recommendations blade again. I want to get back to initial view.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I have updated answer with both disable and get recommendations.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I dont want to get activate again. Even though if I snooze one of the high availability recommendation, it still shows other recommendations. So totally I want to bring to the normal position i.e., no recommendations should be displayed and advisor recommendations blade should be visible as initial state